# Are there scss files for moono-lisa

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Are there somewhere scss files for `moono-lisa` theme? I found css files but I need scss to custom some elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

As you can read in the original depot, there are only css files :

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/tree/major/skins/moono-lisa

But you can override the moono-lisa theme in creating your own including the original css files, and override theme. Take a look at this : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/skin_sdk_intro.html#the-anatomy-of-a-skin

And specially the files `editor.css` with include tags

Extract of the readme :

### Directory Structure

CSS parts:

- **editor.css**: the main CSS file. It's simply loading several other files, for easier maintenance,
- **mainui.css**: the file contains styles of entire editor outline structures,
- **toolbar.css**: the file contains styles of the editor toolbar space (top),
- **richcombo.css**: the file contains styles of the rich combo ui elements on toolbar,
- **panel.css**: the file contains styles of the rich combo drop-down, it's not loaded
  until the first panel open up,
- **elementspath.css**: the file contains styles of the editor elements path bar (bottom),
- **menu.css**: the file contains styles of all editor menus including context menu and button drop-down,
  it's not loaded until the first menu open up,
- **dialog.css**: the CSS files for the dialog UI, it's not loaded until the first dialog open,
- **reset.css**: the file defines the basis of style resets among all editor UI spaces,
- **preset.css**: the file defines the default styles of some UI elements reflecting the skin preference,
- **editor_XYZ.css** and **dialog_XYZ.css**: browser specific CSS hacks.

Other parts:

- **skin.js**: the only JavaScript part of the skin that registers the skin, its browser specific files and its icons and defines the Chameleon feature,
- **images/**: contains a fill general used images,
- **dev/**: contains SVG and PNG source of the skin icons.